# Display text over a clickable image using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I'm trying to display some text over a clickable image. I'm using the InkWell widget to make the image clickable, and the Stack widget to overlay the Text widget:

```
new Expanded(
  child: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new InkWell(
        onTap: (){ _doSomething(); },
        child: Image.asset("images/my-image.jpg"),
      ),
      new Text("Some text"),
    ],
  ),
)
```

This way I can only tap on the image section not filled with the text, and that's not good. I would like my funtion to run even if the overlay text is tapped.

I tried using the FlatButton widget instead of the Text and somehow it works, but I'm sure this is not the proper way to do this. Do you have any advise?

```
new Expanded(
  child: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new InkWell(
        onTap: (){ _doSomething(); },
        child: Image.asset("images/my-image.jpg"),
      ),
      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){_doSomething;},
        child: Text("Some text"),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you'd move the `InkWell` higher up the stack?

```
Expanded(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){ _doSomething(); },
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset("images/my-image.jpg"),
        Text("Some text"),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the stack inside the Inkwell.

```dart
Expanded(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () => _doSomething(),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset("images/my-image.jpg"),
            Text("Some text"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```